# node-sass and sass-eyeglass Get the tree

Tags: javascript, sass, node-sass

I am interested in using sass-eyeglass with node-sass to build some custom functions. One of the things I am looking to do is to retrieve a value of a sass variable like so:

JS:

```
// eyeglass-exports.js
"use strict";

var path = require("path");

module.exports = function(eyeglass, sass) {
  return {
    functions: {
      "get-var($prefix, $subject)": function(prefix, subject, done) {
        // Return the variable {prefix + ' - ' + subject}
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Sass:

```
// index.scss
$my-foo: 20px;

div {
  font-size: get-var(my, foo);
  // font-size: 20px;
}
```

To be able to do something like this, I need to access some kind of tree of everything that has been parsed (at that point in time). Is this possible with node-sass?

Comment: Why would you want to do this at all?

Comment: So I can dynamically lookup variables, similar to the Stylus lookup function: http://stylus-lang.com/docs/bifs.html#lookupname

Comment: Just being able to access variables defined in sass would enable to create functionality such as dot notation too! There's a lot we can do with that one feature.

Comment: You mean, a lot of terrible things you can do?  How is this any better than just writing out the variable?